# How to read aloud a sentence like 'In the year 18.. they decided to move to Bricktown'

Tags: pronunciation, reading

How to read aloud a sentence like 'In the year 18.. they decided to move to Bricktown'? Such sentences are common especially in Victorian literature.

My only option is 'eighteen and something' but I feel that it will not do when reading aloud formal texts, e.g. citations from legal documents included into some fiction books.

Comment: I've seen it a lot in Victorian literature: things like "They had retired to the quiet town of N------."

Comment: This is highly context-dependent, I think: what's the occasion for reading this aloud? If it's suitably informal (reading a story to children, for example), I'd say "in the year 18 mumble".

Comment: In a more formal context I might read it as "In the year eighteen hundred and something"

Comment: Well yes, obviously - it's a universal feature in Victorian writing.  90% of books and stories from say early 1800s? onwards have this.

Answer (score 5):

You would not say "**In the year eighteen *and* something**", since that would not conform to the standard way of reading years. We don't put an "and" except after "hundred". In standard English we normally would say either:

> In the year eighteen something

or

> In the year eighteen hundred and something.

You could use "something", "thus and such", "and such", "some", or any similar phrase. The choice really depends on the register of the work and the interpretation you wish to give it (which might be out of scope for this board). Just consider that "mumble mumble" is extremely informal and perhaps comic, and "thus and such" is more formal and perhaps stilted.

Comment: [In the year of eighteen and one, peg and awl](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HWByzBW2yug)

Comment: @librik yes indeed, although (as in much folk music) dialectal.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that, at the time that this device was commonplace, no one really anticipated that their work would be read aloud (much less the explosion of the audiobook format may decades later!)

When *I* read this kind of thing out loud to my family, I usually say "In the year eighteen[mumble mumble mumble]" but that's a humorous decision, not an informed one...

Answer (score 0):

Usually that kind of approximation is referenced as:

> "In the eighteen hundreds, they decided to..."

It could be refined, if there is any addition clue about that period, into:

> "In the *early* eighteen hundreds, they decided to..."

or

> "In the *late* eighteen hundreds, they decided to..."

Comment: "Usually": Do you have any examples you can cite?

Comment: But that would be paraphrasing, not reading.

Answer (score -3):

How about "Eighteen blippety blip?"

Comment: By far the best answer here to reading out Victorian literature "anonymity underscore."   Joel, I'd say rather than go with a "modern" blippity blip, it's probably better to use something archaic, like underscore --- perhaps "blank" is best.